# What does it mean that the return value of `puts` is `nil`?

Tags: ruby

The output for this code:

```
x = puts 'hello'
puts x
```

was:

```
hello
hello
```

But I expected the output to be one `hello`. `puts x` didn't return the value I expected. I thought `puts x` was the same as `puts 'hello'`. What am I missing?

Comment: I can't reproduce your output. When running the above code, the first line (`x = puts 'hello'`) prints `hello` to *stdout* and the second line (`puts x`) prints an empty line.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you are declaring the value of x to be `puts 'hello'`. The value of x in this case is nil. Try it out in your irb console.

```
x
=> nil
```

If you try to call nil on puts you will get this output

```
puts nil
=>            
   nil
```

As for why the method returns nil

The `puts` method echoes the previous argument to the console. In this case, `nil` is actually the return value.

Here is some info from the documentation

> puts(obj, ...) → nil
>
> Writes the given objects to ios as with IO#print. Writes a record separator (typically a newline) after any that do not already end with a newline sequence. If called with an array argument, writes each element on a new line. If called without arguments, outputs a single record separator.

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/IO.html#method-i-puts

Here is the source code for that method

```
if (argc == 0) {
    rb_io_write(out, rb_default_rs);
    return Qnil;
}
```

Take a look at that last line. `return Qnil;`